# Using different codeception environments

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I am working on some Unit Tests for an API using Codeception. The idea is to make sure that each API call returns the expected response codes and a JSON object in a desired format.

The problem that I have is that I need to use different URLs depending on whether the server is `localhost`, the test server or the production one.

I can't use the values of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` because the tests are not ran through the web browser.

Here http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments they explain that some environments can be set by modifying the configuration file. The documentation doesn't explain how to modify the configuration file to use it within your own unit tests.

Id like to set some environments like `local`, `test`, `production` and then, inside my unit test classes, to know what `URLs` to use. Each environment would have different URLs.

I've read the documentation but I can't find the way to do it.

Do you know any way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Agree, documentation is not clear on if the environment configuration is suite-specific, albeit since sub-configs are merged with the parent config (codeception.yml), it _should_ be possible to configure environments in parent config as well.

Comment: Here is a tutorial I made to do this: https://wp-bdd.com/multiple-environments/ .
Environments can be anything, different browsers, different versions, different data etc.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that your codeception version is at least 1.8, as environment is only supported from 1.8.

Below is our setup for codeception, specified in `api.suite.yml`, with PhpBrowser and REST modules enabled for BDD and API testings:

```
...
env:
    local:
        modules:
            config:
                PhpBrowser:
                    url: http://local.example.com/
                REST:
                    url: http://local.example.com/v1/
    integration:
        modules:
            config:
                PhpBrowser:
                    url: http://integration.example.com/
                REST:
                    url: http://integration.example.com/v1/
    staging:
        modules:
            config:
                PhpBrowser:
                    url: http://staging.example.com/
                REST:
                    url: http://staging.example.com/v1/
```

When running codecept command, you need to provide an `--env` option to specify which environment the tests should use.

Comment: just to be clear, this goes AFTER the whole tree starting with modules:... enabled:... config...

Comment: Is it possible to test against multiple environments in one test?

Comment: @AlxVallejo, yes add additional --env arguments, like this:
`codecept run testSuiteName --env local --env integration --env staging`. But if you want specific test, from test case. Then: `codecept run pathToTestFileWithExtension.php:testMethodName --env local --env integration --env staging`